# Using Django-Admin's Create/Update/Delete templates OUTSIDE of admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am currently prototyping a web application with django and I would like to know whether it's possible to use Django-admin's Create/Update/List html templates outside of Django-admin.

Currently I have the following views:

```
class TaskCreate(CreateView):
    model = Task
    fields = ['priority', 'title', 'content', 'visible_to', 'awake_at', 'is_completed']


class TaskUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Task
    fields = ['priority', 'title', 'content', 'visible_to', 'awake_at', 'is_completed']


class TaskDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Task
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tasks-list')
```

When I visit TaskCreate's view, I would like to have a form that renders all the correct widgets for different types of fields defined in my model.

Comment: Django's generic views already do this. Have you looked at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView

How is your requirement different?

Comment: @rtindru OP wants to use the templates (HTML) as well.

Comment: @rtindru exactly what Selcuk said

Comment: @Sparrowcide Oh so you can just specify a new template in the View classes such as `template_name=task_detail.html'
And inside `task_detail.html` just extend from `admin/base_site.html` or `admin/change_list.html` -> not sure if this works buy give it a shot! Might need some minor modifications